# Create custom Docker Image works, using the installed mysql-connector-python in a Container does not

Tags: python, docker, dockerfile, mysql-python

I want to deploy a small Python app that connects with a (currently running locally) MySQL server. Within `./fzwk-app/` I created a module `database` with `DBController.py`:

```py
class DbController(object):
    def __init__(self):
        self._db_connection = mysql.connector.connect(
            host='localhost',
            user='foo',
            passwd='bar',
            database='mydb'
        )
        self._db_cur = self._db_connection.cursor()
# ...
```

When running my small app by running `./fzwk-app/__init__.py` locally on my dev device, the db connection works just fine.
Now I wanted to start deploying to a docker container.
First, I set up the Dockerfile like this:

```
FROM python:3.6
ADD ./fzwk-app/ /
RUN pip3 install mysql-connector
CMD [ "python", "./__init__.py" ]
```

Building the Docker Image works just fine (`docker build -t fzwk-app:0.1 .`), but when I try to create and run a container (`docker run fzwk-app`), I am greeted with the following Python traceback:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "./__init__.py", line 21, in <module>
    from database import DbController as db
  File "/database/DbController.py", line 18, in <module>
    import mysql.connector
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'mysql'
```

Where's my mistake?

Comment: i guess you just need to expose what port you will expose your container in your computer. try adding EXPOSE <port_number> to your dockerfile and see if that works. 
EX: EXPOSE 5000

Comment: Thanks for your input, @MarceloFonseca. I am going to look further into creating a whole stack with a decent `docker-compose.yml` setup; for now my task is just to create an image that will work an run my small Python app... So, no need to expose anything so far...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I managed to make it work by changing my Dockerfile to

```
FROM python:3.6
ADD ./fzwk-app/ /fzwk-app/
RUN pip3 install mysql-connector-python
CMD [ "python", "/fzwk-app/__init__.py" ]
```

So, it seems that `pip install mysql-connector-python` made the change, I guess (even though I also moved the location of my app on the image, but that's more for a better overview when doing a `docker exec -it fzwk-app /bin/bash`...

At least now I am getting the expected

```
_mysql_connector.MySQLInterfaceError: Can't connect to MySQL server on 'localhost' (99)
```

error cause it can't connect with my db, but for that I am planning on building a stack with `docker-compose` anyway.

Hope this will help anyone -- if not, it'll probably help future-me :-)